# Validity of Born Rule

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, interference, probability, born-rule

The Born rule has been very successful in quantum mechanics. However, the interesting fact about this rule is that it only allows pairwise interference. In other words, there are no interference terms that involve three or more slits. Experiments have been conducted if this is strictly true in triple slit experiments(or five slits) and according to the results, Born's rule held within experimental error bounds.

Three Slits:

> Ruling Out Multi-Order Interference in Quantum Mechanics. Urbasi Sinha et al. [*Science* **329**, 418 (2010)](https://dx.doi.org/10.1126/science.119054), [arXiv:1007.4193](https://arxiv.org/abs/1007.4193).

Five Slits:

> Obtaining tight bounds on higher-order interferences with a 5-path interferometer. Thomas Kauten et al. [*New J. Phys.* **19**, 033017 (2017)](https://doi.org/10.1088/1367-2630/aa5d98).

Another related article about Born rule violation is

> Which-way double slit experiments and Born rule violation. J. Quach. [*Phys. Rev. A* **95**, 042129 (2017)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.95.042129), [arXiv:1610.06401](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.06401).

In that paper, Dr. Quach proposed another parameter in testing the Born rule. (Past experiments used the Sorkin parameter to verify the Born rule.)

In the double slit experiment, according to Born's rule,
$$\lvert A+B\rvert^2 = \lvert A\rvert^2 +\lvert B\rvert^2 + A^*B + B^*A$$

If we add another slit, according to Born's rule,
$$\lvert A+B+C\rvert^2 = \lvert A\rvert^2 +\lvert B\rvert^2 + \lvert C\rvert^2+ I_{AB} + I_{AC} + I_{BC}$$

Notice that there is no interference term that involves A, B and C all at once, i.e. there is no $I_{ABC}$.

A generalized probabilistic theory might allow higher-order interference terms involving 3 or more slits and not just pairwise. What if these higher-order interference terms really exist but are somehow 'restricted' to be small, either by the set-up of the experiments, or it might be restricted by a quantum mechanical law that we don't know yet.

**Question: How can we estimate the contribution of $I_{ABC}$ or higher-order interference in general?**

Comment: You don't mean $|A+B+C|^2$, do you? Otherwise, it's obvious you could not get triple products.

Comment: @LucJ.Bourhis According to Born's Rule, triple products are not allowed but only pairwise. But what if the Born's rule is just a very good approximation and there are indeed higher-order interference terms (just like the one I proposed above) but these terms are just very small.

Comment: I_{ABC} is real, isn't it? Then a linear combination of the real part of $ABC$, $A^*BC$, $AB^*C$ and $ABC^*$?

Comment: @LucJ.Bourhis I_{ABC} should be real.

Comment: http://science.sciencemag.org/content/329/5990/418

Comment: @LucJ.Bourhis I added another guess. Is the 2nd guess more valid than the first? Thanks.

Comment: Related https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/348091/implication-of-borns-rule-on-the-superposition-principle

Comment: So... the idea is to just wildly guess at possible reformulations of the Born rule, without *any* underlying principle to back them up? I don't think you really understood the real physical content of the publications you've cited.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Of course "guessing reformulations" without any underlying principle to back them up is not a good idea. My point here is to know what others think about possible reformulations of Born rule especially higher order interference terms. The original Born rule was unexpectedly, kind of a "guess" by Max Born himself. See http://www.preposterousuniverse.com/blog/2014/07/24/why-probability-in-quantum-mechanics-is-given-by-the-wave-function-squared/ The Born rule we know today was only added as a footnote to his original rejected paper.

Comment: @J.B.Dumale Indeed the Born rule, in its initial formulation, was a wild guess, which is a justified strategy when there is experimental data to be explained and no working explanations. Are you claiming this is the case here? If so, what experimental data are left unexplained by the Born rule? If not, what kind of response are you looking for, beyond 'we agree with you in that your strategy of wild guesses is not a good idea'?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Thank you for your insight. I am also working with other approaches to this problem that don't involve guessing. However, my post here is not entirely a 'wild guess'. The interference term for two slits is a sum of the products of their real and imaginary parts respectively (with a factor of 2). What if the 'triple interference term' is also similar to this form but somehow it was "restricted" to be very small.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I edited the post and asked a similar question. Is the new question still too broad? Thanks.

Comment: @J.B.Dumale I personally still don't understand why you need an $I_{ABC}$ at all. The literature you quote *does* provide reasons for it (the first two, to provide experimental bounds for it; the third, to understand the role of multi-slit trajectories in the path-integral formalism), but you don't posit any such foundations. I personally think in its current form this is too broad and too shapeless for this format to provide useful answers, but your edit is [in review](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/189491) and it's not up to me.